# What product is created in a zinc - nitrate reaction?

Tags: redox, solutions

**Question:**

> Place 2 mL of Nitric acid in a test tube and add a small piece of Zinc turning

I thought that the overall net ionic equation would be:

$$\ce{Zn + 2H+ -> Zn^2+ + H2}$$

Is this correct? Is the zinc oxidized and the hydrogen reduced? Or have I got this completely wrong?

Comment: You have to consider oxidative properties of nitric acid, being reduced to NO2, NO, or even NH4+.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.
The net ionic reaction between zinc metal and nitric acid can be written:
$$ \ce{Zn + 2 H+(aq) -> Zn^2+(aq) + H2(g)} $$
The oxidation state of zinc changes as it is oxidized from 0 to +2.
Similarly, hydrogen's state changes as it reduces from +1 to 0.